# Handle Illegal Query Parameters

Tags: node.js, rest, aws-lambda

How do I return a 400/404 if someone is passing extra or unwanted params in query to my REST API endpoint?

For example if my endpoint is:

```
/resource?param1=abc
```

then if someone does:

```
/resource?param1=abc&illegalParam=xyz
```

How do I throw a HTTP 400/404 error? I am guessing I have to try to read everything that is passed into the query, how do I do that?

Also please note I am using AWS Lambda (node) for my application.

Comment: Can you explain why this is is a concern?

Comment: How do you parse the parameters now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something like -

```
const queryParams = Object.keys(event.queryStringParameters); 
const requiredParams = ['param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4']; 
if (!queryParams.every((param) => requiredParams.includes(param))) { 
   throw new BadRequest('Illegal query parameters passed'); 
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks better and more scalable! Cool! Going to keep it for my team 

Answer (score 0):

Just access the `event.queryStringParameters` object and parse it according to your business rules.

```js
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  if(event && 
       event.queryStringParameters &&
       event.queryStringParameters.illegalParam) {
     return {
        "statusCode": "200",
        "body": JSON.stringify({ hasIllegalParam: true }),
     }
  }
};
```